New Excel doc "Automatic update of links has been disabled" when executing macro from QAT
I get "Automatic update of links has been disabled" when I try to execute a macro from the QAT. I tell it to enable updates then I get "Sorry, Excel can't open two workbooks with the same name at the same time." I have only the one workbook open.
I do NOT get the security notice when I open the workbook (as has been mentioned in other posts about update of links message). I do NOT get the security notice for Word 365 or Outlook 365.
That happens for existing documents (without links) and new workbooks (documents).
If I say to disable link updates, I get a VBA error 400.
If I go to the VB editor to run the macro or run it from the Developer tab/ribbon the macro works fine.
That happens for all macros in my QAT.
I have checked for links but considering it happens in a new blank workbook I wouldn't expect any.
Any ideas?
I'm on W10 22H2 with Microsoft 365 (Office 365) if that matters.

I took an image of my QAT from Options > Customize QAT so I'd remember the order and icons used for each macro.
I then removed them from the QAT and the added them back. (There were only 5 of them.)
I no longer get the enable updates security notices. The macros just execute normally.
Not sure how or why it stopped working, but hey, that's Microsoft/Office for you.
